# SetInputToWaveFile

Tags: c#, audio, input, speech

i am new to c# and am currently working on a project that involves me using an audio file as input and write it as text. I have the code which uses the system.speech. I got this code from http://blog.thomascsherman.com/2009/08/getting-started-with-windows-voice-recognition/
and it compiles, but i am having trouble at run time. As soon as i run it the code crashes and the console says "the input file is not found". I realised what the path for the input file is and i know the the file is in that folder. Please help me with this. I am pasting the code below.

using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Speech;
using System.Speech.Recognition;
using System.Speech.AudioFormat;

public class Hello
{

```
public static void Main()
{
     Hello hello= new Hello();
        hello.doStuff();


}



private void doStuff()
{
    SpeechRecognitionEngine sre = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();
    sre.SpeechHypothesized += new EventHandler<SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechHypothesized);
    sre.SpeechRecognized += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognized);
    sre.RecognizeCompleted += new EventHandler<RecognizeCompletedEventArgs>(sre_RecognizeCompleted);
    sre.AudioSignalProblemOccurred += new EventHandler<AudioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs>(sre_AudioSignalProblemOccurred);
    sre.SpeechDetected += new EventHandler<SpeechDetectedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechDetected);
    sre.SpeechRecognitionRejected += new EventHandler<SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs>(sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected);



    DictationGrammar dg = new DictationGrammar();
    sre.LoadGrammar(dg);


    sre.SetInputToWaveFile("hello.wav");
    sre.EndSilenceTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);


    sre.RecognizeAsync();
}

 void sre_SpeechHypothesized(object sender, SpeechHypothesizedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
}
 void sre_AudioSignalProblemOccurred(object sender, AudioSignalProblemOccurredEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.AudioSignalProblem.ToString());
}

 void sre_SpeechRecognitionRejected(object sender, SpeechRecognitionRejectedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Rejected!");
}

 void sre_RecognizeCompleted(object sender, RecognizeCompletedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Recognition Complete!");
}

 void sre_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text);
}

 void sre_SpeechDetected(object sender, SpeechDetectedEventArgs e)
{
Console.WriteLine("Speech Detected!");
}


}
```

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, try setting an absolute path (I.e. @"C:/my/file/is/here/hello.wav") to determine if it's the path that's the problem or something else.

Also note that there are different folders for Release and Debug builds, which can be confusing at times. Make sure that the file *really* is in the correct folder (to test if this is the problem, put hello.wav in both Release and Debug folders to begin with).

Comment: Hi,I tried that but it is not working it gives the same error "Could not find a part of the path "C:/Users/Owner/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/Learning/bin/Release/hello.wav" " Please help.

Comment: If you copy the file to both Release and Debug, and run the program (*without* the absolute path, just "hello.wav"), do you still get the same error?

Comment: Ya i am getting the exact same error..i dont know why it is doing that

Comment: Try putting the file in a somewhat less user-specific location, i.e. directly under C:\ (and using an absolut path in the program). While I'm mostly guessing here, that error you're getting seems to be related to access permissions.

Comment: I tried that but the same error is coming...now i actually think it might be something to do with the code, what do you suggest?

Comment: Hey..i think i just fixed the input problem, i accidently named the file wrongly. Well putting that aside, atleast the program doesnt crash now, but it still doesnt show me the audio in text. I want to know have i written the code correct to show me the text in the console?